# for double loop in R

Tags: r, loops

```
for(i in 0:3) {
    for (j in quantile(0:80,probs=c(0,0.33,0.67,1))) {
        print(paste(i,j,sep=","))
    }
}
```

Generate:

```
"0,0"  
"0,26.4"  
"0,53.6"  
"0,80"  
"1,0"  
"1,26.4"  
.  
.  
.
```

What about generating like below:

```
"0,0"  
"1,26.4"  
"2,53.6"  
"3,80"  
?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't really need a for loop for that:

```
paste(0:3,quantile(0:80,probs=c(0,0.33,0.67,1)),sep=",")
```

gives:

```
[1] "0,0"    "1,26.4" "2,53.6" "3,80"
```

If you want to print it in that specific way you could just loop over this result and print.

Comment: @ Sacha Epskamp thanks, and if I write text(-0.05, (i + 1)/4, sprintf("%3.2f", j)?

Comment: In a plot? Both `text` and `sprintf` can be used vectorized, so `text(1.05, (0:3 + 1)/4, sprintf("%3.2f",quantile(0:80,probs=c(0,0.33,0.67,1))))` works.